# How to correctly run powershell script with here-strings?

Tags: python, shell, powershell, sharepoint, escaping

I am working with Sharepoint service. My python script runs powershell script and download file. I have following powershell script for downloading file from Sharepoint:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[String]$UserName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
[String]$Password,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=3)]
[String]$FileUrl,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
[String]$DestinationFilePathName
)

try
{
    # Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM.
    Add-Type -Path ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client").location)
    Add-Type -Path ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime").location)

    # Create a credential object using the username and password supplied.
    $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $client.Credentials = $Creds
    $client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
    Write-Host "Downloading file" $FileUrl "to" $DestinationFilePathName -ForegroundColor Green
    $client.DownloadFile($FileUrl, $DestinationFilePathName)
    $client.Dispose()
}
catch
{
    # Error occurred.
    $_.Exception.Message
    $exitcode = -1
}
exit $exitcode
```

In python powershell script is called by the following code:

```
...
shell_script = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command \"& %s %s %s %s %s\"" % (self.config['path_shell_download_script'], user_email, self.password, self.config['url_download_from_sp'], self.config['sp_extract_path'])
        if subprocess.call(shell_script, shell=True) != 0:
            raise Exception("Error while retrieving file: %s." % (self.config['url_download_from_sp']))
...
```

Everything ok, this script works with my credentials correctly. But when i try run script with admin credentials it does not work. Problems with password of admin, because password is something like - @'M@+12w-zT!3Lv)

How i can correctly escape this symbols in my password?

Comment: You could mitigate this a little easier by encoding your command. Guessing it should be easy to convert command text (not the parameters) to a bas64 string then you can pass that to `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand 234132==` for example. that way you don't have to account for single quotes and double quotes etc. Also, I do not see any here-string in this question so you might need to double check what a here-string is

Comment: @Matt the `@'` is the syntax to open here-string.  If the password is being passed unquoted then powershell might be interpreting it as a here-string.

Comment: That's it. I wasn't really looking at the password.  Yes that would need to be escaped. My suggestion is still valid but might be overkill

Comment: @Matt, agreed. OP should probably first try quoting the password and escaping the`@` with a backtick `[string]$Password =  "\`@Ps#$#22" `

Comment: @Matt, thanks, but not working :(

Comment: *"My python script runs powershell script and download file"* Why? Python is perfectly capable of downloading files by itself.